# Set spring jackson beanpropertyfilters in controller

Tags: java, json, spring, filter, jackson

I'm trying to serialize a hierarchy of objects using jackson, but I must use different fields in each controller method. Currently, I do this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/chat/message/create",
            headers = "Accept=application/json", 
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
            method = RequestMethod.GET
            )
    @Transactional
    public @ResponseBody
    ChatMessage createChatMessage(@RequestParam("chat_id") Integer chatId, 
            @RequestParam("chat_from_id") Integer chatFromId,
            @RequestParam("chat_content") String content) {

        User fromUser = userDAO.find(User.class, chatFromId);

        ChatMessage message = new ChatMessage();
        message.setContent(content);
        message.setLastUpdateDate(new Date());
        message.setFromUser(fromUser);

        Chat chat = chatDAO.find(Chat.class, chatId);
        message.setChat(chat);

        chatMessageDAO.save(message);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
        FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider()
            .addFilter("chatMessageFilter", SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept(Collections.EMPTY_SET));
        ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer(filters);
        try {
            return writer.writeValueAsString(message);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The problem is I want to use MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter, but I cannot find a way to set the filter provider of list of beanpropertyfilters on it. I WANT to do something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/chat/message/create",
            headers = "Accept=application/json", 
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
            method = RequestMethod.GET
            )
    @Transactional
    public @ResponseBody
    ChatMessage createChatMessage(@RequestParam("chat_id") Integer chatId, 
            @RequestParam("chat_from_id") Integer chatFromId,
            @RequestParam("chat_content") String content) {

        User fromUser = userDAO.find(User.class, chatFromId);

        ChatMessage message = new ChatMessage();
        message.setContent(content);
        message.setLastUpdateDate(new Date());
        message.setFromUser(fromUser);

        Chat chat = chatDAO.find(Chat.class, chatId);
        message.setChat(chat);

        chatMessageDAO.save(message);

        getFilterProvider().addFilter("chatMessageFilter", SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept(Collections.EMPTY_SET));

        return message;
    }
```

The getFilterProvider() would get the FilterProvider that is used by MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter. That way, I would set 5 or 6 filters in one method, and a completely different set of filters in another method.

Note: Json views will not help me here. They are way too static, and I can't combine to specify which views to use for nested objects.